# Mount a partition in Terminal with udisks

Tags: linux, udisks

I'm running Linux Mint 17.1, based on Ubuntu Trusty.

If I run

```
udisks --mount /dev/sda7
```

then the partition is mounted in `/media` and not in `/media/$USER` as it should. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What is the setting for `ENV{UDISKS_FILESYSTEM_SHARED}` in the file `/etc/udev/rules.d/99-udisks2.rules`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As @don_crissti suggests, I was indeed using udisks 1. I should've done

```
udisksctl mount -b /dev/sda7
```

Answer (score 1):

Taken from [the Arch Linux wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Udisks#Mount_to_.2Fmedia_.28udisks2.29) for this program:

> By default, udisks2 mounts removable drives
>   under the ACL controlled directory `/run/media/$USER/`. If you wish to
>   mount to `/media` instead, use this rule:

```
/etc/udev/rules.d/99-udisks2.rules
# UDISKS_FILESYSTEM_SHARED
# ==1: mount filesystem to a shared directory (/media/VolumeName)
# ==0: mount filesystem to a private directory (/run/media/$USER/VolumeName)
# See udisks(8)
ENV{ID_FS_USAGE}=="filesystem|other|crypto", ENV{UDISKS_FILESYSTEM_SHARED}="1"
```

The last line of this file, specifically the setting `ENV{UDISKS_FILESYSTEM_SHARED}="1"` seems to control whether or not the device file is mounted at `/media/$USER` or just `/media`.

Comment: Note the OP system appears to be using `udisks1` (as it's using `udisks -mount` which is no longer present in `udisks2` -  replaced by `udisksctl -mount`) and  iirc `UDISKS_FILESYSTEM_SHARED`  was added in v. _2.0.X_ (I don't remember the exact release number)